# Как выбрать N элементов массива?

Tags: python

Имеются два заданных массива -- в одном m элементов, в другом n. Как вывести в обоих массивах первые n элементов?

m меньше n.

Comment: Может наоборот: m > n?

Answer (score 1):

Есть просто созданная для этого стандартная функция `zip` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7]
for x, y in zip(a, b):
   print x, y
```

Вывод:

```
1 5
2 6
3 7
```

Если есть только один список из которого нужно вывести первые `n` элементов (или все, если `n` больше длины списка):

```
for x, _ in zip(lst, xrange(n)):
   print x
```

П.С. В питоне нет массивов, есть списки.